# Insert MySql record for every file in a directory using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run a script to scan a directory (In this case "/images") and create a new MySQL record in a table called "images" for each one there.

I haven't used PHP in years (maybe since 2005) so I'm not too up to date on MYSQLi - but I've given it a crack and the error message I'm getting is suggesting I've got problem on the final IF statement but it's completely stumped me here is what I have so far - do not expect it to be elegant!

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myplaceholderusernameforstack";
$password = "myplaceholderpasswordforstack";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


if ($handle = opendir('images')) {

//This is to loop over the directory.
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if($file!='.' && $file!='..') {
        $images[] = "('".$file."')";
    }
}

closedir($handle);
}

//Insert into DB
$query = "INSERT INTO images (filename) VALUES ".implode(',', $images)." ";
if (!mysqli_query($query)) {
   print mysqli_error();
}
else {
print "finished installing your images!";
}


?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: also loop `//Insert into DB part` instead of using implode. then you will insert a record for every file.

Comment: correct INSERT syntax is...  `INSERT INTO [table] ([columns]) VALUES ([values])`  .. you missed the hookes within your VALUES statement

Comment: you need to specify the connection for the mysqli_query function, try `mysqli_query($conn,$query)` more here [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: It think that the problem is the implode. You should explode.